# Will Xamarin work for what I want it to do?

Tags: c#, wpf, macos, visual-studio, xamarin

I'm a 1st year computer science student and we currently code in C# using Visual Studio, the only problem is that I have a mac, already you see the problem. In order for me to use VS I have to run it through a VM which is slow and not very memory friendly.

Basically I need to be able to write C# code with a GUI to present it and for my tutors (the people who mark my work) to be able to use it easily as well.

So the question is: Can I use Xamarin to create WPF applications or their equivalent on mac with relatively few issues? / How easily could I replace VS with Xamarin if I can at all?

Comment: Easy answer, no you can´t. Xamarin is a framework for building mobile apps.

Comment: @MarcelTheis Incorrect, there is Xamarin.Mac. It doesn't support WPF though.

Comment: Yes, you are right!

Comment: Both GTK# and Xamarin.Mac provide you the UI framework to attack. They are equivalent to WPF in many aspects though not all, and they have different design philosophies.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to create WPF applications on OS X. You can build apps for Mac OS X with Xamarin but I think this is not your best choice. If you want to do it that way, [here is some info:](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/mac/getting_started/hello,_mac/)

You can also try to use Boot Camp and dual boot Windows and OS X. However, you must have a copy of Windows. Probably your university provides free licenses to students, but you should check that.